# How to handle Multiple OfflineImap with Gpg stored Passwords?

Tags: email, terminal, gnupg, mutt, offlineimap

I am using Offlineimap with gpgp stored passwords. Pretty similar to this setup

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44214/encrypt-offlineimap-password

My issue is this. I have multiple email accoutns, and it is tedious to enter the same Gnupg password over and over again while trying to sync.

I tried the priming thing the user mentions in that article but it does not work me, in fact OfflineImap tries to pass the actual Gpg password to the mail server. So I assume that is botched.

The other issue is that I cannot use the Gnome Keyring type stuff because I do not have Gnome/Kde etc. I am using ssh terminal for that.

I am on Debian Wheezy 32b, it has Py 2.7

What are my options?

thanks

Comment: Are you using one or multiple keys for your mail addresses? If you're using a single key, you should be able to configure `gpg-agent`. If you're using multiple keys, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I am using single key however the solution has to be terminal friendly since I cant get gpg-agent window

Comment: There is also a (n)curses based implementation, if you can have an interactive terminal (which you seem to have).

Comment: If the hint on the curses-implementation worked for you, I will reformulate the comment as an answer.

Comment: Jens thanks for the point, Iactually figured out after you mentioned it. Surprisinglu It works great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GnuPG 2 (in Debian and derivatives installed as `gpg2`) can connect with `gpg-agent` caching your passphrase. If you use a graphical user interface, you will probably know it from its key entry window, but there's also a command line version `pinentry-curses`, that does not require any window manager. In Debian and derrivative distributions, it's in the package `pinentry-curses`:

```
pinentry-curses - curses-based PIN or pass-phrase entry dialog for GnuPG
```

Make sure to configure it in `.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

See the Arch Wiki for [configuring `gpg-agent`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#gpg-agent)

Install `gnupg2` & change `/usr/bin/gpg` to be a symlink to `/usr/bin/gpg2` (removing `gnupg` breaks Debian).

For anyone using `duply` on Debian Wheezy & having problems with `pinentry-curses` - use [`duply 1.9.0`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftplicity/files/duply%20%28simple%20duplicity%29/) not `1.5.5` in the repos (this fixes problems signing backups with `gpg`).

`pinentry-curses` now works without any problems when called programmatically. This also fixes `gpg` problems with `fwknop`